# Running batch file from Task Scheduler in Win7 using QODBC and Quickbooks does not work

Tags: task-scheduler, quickbooks

I have a batch file (.BAT) set up on a Windows 7 PC running QB Premier 2012 that uses a SQL client to connect to a Quickbooks company file through QODBC (latest version) that works fine when run ad hoc by the user (i.e., connection works, QODBC panels show and I get good output in the extracts).

However, when trying to schedule the  batch file in Task Scheduler it appears to run but I get empty output files.  I have been through all the possibilities of TS configuration on this (local security policy settings for logon as batch, configuring the batch file to run as administrator, ad nauseum...) without success.  Also tried the AT command but was also not successful.

I believe the issue is that TS does not run the process in interactive mode and since the TS EXE is initiating the connection as the parent calling image QB probably wants to authorize the connection again, but since we don't get any UI when run from TS it's tough luck.

Any insights much appreciated as this has been a time thief like you would not believe.

Answer (score 0):

Flexquarters states that the user must be logged into QuickBooks or the QODBC process will not run successfully.  They told me that this was due to the QuickBooks SDK requirements and there was nothing Flexquarters could do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that having your program to run as a console app would allow QuickBooks to authorize connection from the console application itself instead of the Task Scheduler. Hope someone would find this helpful.